# Picasso: Why is my cardview changes its dimension when the image load?

Tags: java, android, picasso

I used Picasso in loading my Image and my problem is about my cardview it change its Dimension when the Image loads . it looks like this;
Before The  [image(1)](https://ibb.co/nCyE7a) loads  and looks like this after the [Image(2)](https://ibb.co/j09yYF)
How do I make my dimension fixed even when the image loads. here is my codes
drawer_layout_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/partner_post_image"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/partner_store"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom|start"
                android:text="Store Name"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/partner_post_desc"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="top|start"
                android:text="Description Here"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and my RecyclerView.Holder code is like this

```
public class PartnerStoreViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private View mView;
    public PartnerStoreViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mView = itemView;
    }

    public void setStore(String store ){
        TextView storeName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.partner_store);
        storeName.setText(store);
    }
    public void setDescription(String description){
        TextView descName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.partner_post_desc);
        descName.setText(description);
    }
    public void setImage(Context context, String image){
        ImageView postImage = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.partner_post_image);
        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(image)
                .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_blu_logo)
                .fit()
                .into(postImage);
    }
}
```

my Fragment code and adapter

```
public class PartnerStore extends BaseFragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PartnersList, PartnerStoreViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    private DatabaseReference mRef;

    public PartnerStore() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_partner_store, container, false);

        mRef = MyDatabaseUtil.getDatabase().getReference().child("partners");

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.partner_store_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PartnersList, PartnerStoreViewHolder>(
                PartnersList.class,
                R.layout.drawer_partner_store_list,
                PartnerStoreViewHolder.class,
                mRef
        ){
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(PartnerStoreViewHolder viewHolder, PartnersList model, int position) {
                viewHolder.setStore(model.getPartnerStore());
                viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
                viewHolder.setImage(getActivity() ,model.getImage());
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.cleanup();
    }
}
```

thanks..

**UPDATE**
My problem was I never used the space In my Texview, Though I still dont know why it changes the dimension. well, I cheated on my textview and I added white spaces to use the unused spaced from my textview I implemented it like this goes like this...

```
public void setDescription(String description){
        TextView descName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.partner_post_desc);
        if (description.length() <= 30){
            for (int x=0; x <= 99; x++){
                description = description + " "; //adding white spaces
            }
            descName.setText(description);
        }else {
            descName.setText(description);
        }
    }
```

Thanks to All that helped.. I appreciate it

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent" of your imageview

Comment: Yes, sir I tried that still didnt solve it..

Comment: can you please post the onCreateViewHolder() method here ?

Comment: @KunalChawla thats all i got from the view holder i used firebase recylerview library for this..

Comment: Okay. Could you try adding the attribute `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to your `ImageView` and then see if it works as you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are giving only third part of view to textviews and one other two parts to imageview's parent layout which is not being used because imageview width is fixed . you should't be using weight at all as you are giving fixed width and height to imageview and wrap content for textviews.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/partner_post_image"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/partner_store"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom|start"
            android:text="Store Name"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/partner_post_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="top|start"
            android:text="Description Here"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and then try

```
Picasso.with(context)
    .load(image)
    .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_blu_logo)
    .fit()
    .centerCrop()
    .into(postImage);
```

let me know if you still have any issues.

Comment: I got ur point sir thanks ,well im anticipating the data might be few or a lot .. i put a lot of text to fill in .. and it work just as I wanted.. but what I have thought of.. is what if I have only few texts.. how can I still make my view fixed? Do u have suggestion..

Comment: okay if you have few texts, what you wanna do? centre the text or what?

Comment: Just align to left

Comment: you can achieve that by checking if text length is less than your range, set the gravity of textview parent layout to left. got it?

Comment: sir, another thing why does it change after the image loads.. if u dont mind looking my post.. the image1 seems to be doing fine with the place holder.. but at the moment it loads it push the cardview to the left?

Comment: because you are using fit() and cetreCrop() in Picasso. you can add following lines to remove this effect    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" in imageview xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach.

```
Picasso.with(context)
        .load(image)
        .error(android.R.drawable.stat_notify_error)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_blu_logo)
        .fit()
        .centerCrop()
        .into(postImage);
```

use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` inside your xml ImageView.
did you try `android:layout_width="match_parent"` inside your ImageView ?